# Pairing elements of two lists in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

In Google Earth Engine, I have two lists:

```
var list1 = ee.List.sequence(50, 100, 50);
var list2 = ee.List.sequence(2,3,1);
```

How to make a new list containing every possible pair from list1 to list2 ?

I tried zip() function which gave results as follows:
[
  [
    50,
    2
  ],
  [
    100,
    3
  ]
].

Pairs [50,3] and [100,2] are missing from this new list.
Is there any way out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var list1 = ee.List.sequence(50, 100, 50);
var list2 = ee.List.sequence(2,3,1);

var combinations = ee.List(
  list1.iterate(function (e1, acc) {
    var pairs = list2.map(function (e2) {
      return [e1, e2]
    })
    return ee.List(acc).cat(pairs)
  }, ee.List([]))
)
print(combinations)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b9ad524cd9a16b1f7dcc2720098aba1

Comment: That solves a problem I am facing... but I would like to understand what the acc stands for?

Comment: That's the accumulator. Starting out as an empty list, then you update it for every iteration

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it's much more clear